# Need change message properties (subject etc.) in read scenario

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

Have a question that may look strange, but i have by project requirements implement the following feature for outlook web app (content app) for read mode - updating the subject of item (message or appointment) being viewed.
Approaches tryed:

1) getCallbackTokenAsync - getting error at server side that not enough permissions to update item from EWS.

2) getUserIdentityTokenAsync - getting error at server side  not enough permissionsto call ConvertId at server side, and "Legacy Item Id format error at client side when tryed to call UdateItem at client side or server-side.

3) getting user consent and token via OAuth 2 access code flow - failure (in IE navigation is blocked due to iframe sandbox, and window.open is owerriden by MS for that app iframe) (in Chrome navigation is allowed, and in theory it would work, but the urls like /api/items/{exchange item id} are result to error 404.11 (double escaping detected when sent from sandbox iframe).

4) getting access token at server-side with grant_type=client_credentials [with client id and client secret] works but resulted token is considered as "low security" (protection level 1 while level 2 is necessary). Known that form errors 401 Unauthorized with x-ms-diagnostics header being returned on try to update item.

PS: Just remind I trying update item at READ view, not at edit/compose mode.

Thanks for help!

PS: Application-wide certificate auth call with ADAL as i makingi t looks like so:

```
    public async Task<JObject> PrepareApplicationAuthenticationToken()
    {
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(
            GetAuthorityUrl()
            .ToString()
        );

        var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
            GetResourceUrl(),
            new ClientAssertionCertificate(GetClientId(), AppCertificateHelper.GetCertificate())
        );

        var token = JSON.LoadFromString(result.Serialize());
        token["access_token"] = result.AccessToken;
        token["refresh_token"] = result.RefreshToken;
        return token;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client credential flow requires you to use a certificate rather than a client ID/secret combo. You can use a self-signed certificate as long as you upload it to your app registration manifest. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx for details.

Comment: How i can upload manifest, if i don't have full control over the AD directory? (Full AD support requires Pro subscription as i see).
I registered my app in AD with "Add Connected service" of Visual Studio 2013, not in a normal AD UI at Azure portal...

Comment: No, it doesn't require pro. https://github.com/jasonjoh/office365-azure-guides/blob/master/RegisterAnAppInAzure.md

Comment: "However, when I clicked on it I was never asked for a credit card or any sort of billing information. It just went through the process of enabling portal access." is a bit non-obvious...
It required for me to go through full azure registration screen (with phone number, and other personal details to enter), that is why i was "messed up". and actually this scary screen is true reason to ask my question.

Comment: Understood. We're working with the Azure folks on improving that process for app developers.